# При скроллинге до блока применяется стиль что написать в условии?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Что написать в условии, чтобы когда верхняя часть(граница) браузера достигла блока с классом block приминился стиль?

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ( //Если "верхушка" окна коснулась блок с классом .block){
$('.block').addClass("fixed");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var position = $('.block').position().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  if (position <= 0) $('.block').addClass("fixed");
});
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h39eow6s/)